# using pymysql to get data from mysql but return nan

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

I try to get some data from mysql with python but return nan.
There is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types
from pandas.io import sql
import pymysql
import numpy as np

db = pymysql.connect(host='192.0.0.0',port=0000,user='123',passwd='123321',db='matomo',charset='utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()

try:
    SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
        '''SELECT name FROM matomo_site''',db
    )
    df0=pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['a'])

except:
    print("Error")
    db.rollback()
 
db.close()

print(df0)
```

and the result:

```
    a
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
```

And the mysql data on matomo_site:

```
idsite  name
1       Example
2       abc
3       def
```

I should output the data like:

```
    a
0 Example
1 abc
2 def
```

Is this because my data is in encrypted dataspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem you set column `a`, which not exist in `DataFrame`, so is returned column `a` filled by missing values.

You need change:

```
df0=pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['a'])
```

to:

```
df0 = pd.read_sql_query(
    '''SELECT name FROM matomo_site''',db
).rename(columns={'name':'a'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

because `read_sql_query` return `DataFrame`, so only added `rename` with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and `drop=True` if need default `RangeIndex`.